# Query on useEffect - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am developing an application where I need to make multiple API calls on page load and I need to alter the single state of the component upon each API call. The architecture looks like below.

```
const [stateForm, setStateForm] = useState(.....)

useEffect(()=>{
//FIRST API CALL
setStateForm({....})
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
//SECOND API CALL
setStateForm({....})
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
//THIRD API CALL
setStateForm({....})
},[])

//SO ON.....
```

My question is : Is it a okay to cause side effects in this way? Will altering state in each useEffect hook cause mutiple re-renders?

Comment: You can also use promises for your calles. fetch().then(() => fetch()...)

Comment: each setStateForm cause multiply rerender. Look at answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521912/multiple-fetch-data-axios-with-react-hooks

Comment: "Will altering state in each useEffect hook cause mutiple re-renders?" - almost certainly yes, unless the come simultaneously.

Comment: Also `setStateForm` does not merge state object as `setState` method on `Component` did. So each call will override entire `stateForm`. If you need to merge state use callback `setStateForm(prevState => ({/* merge here */}))`

Comment: Multiple useEffect only make sense if their dependencies are different - in your case it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a okay to cause side effects in this way?

There is nothing wrong so it's generally ok. But it's hard to say anything more definite beyond that - there is not much information to judge about this pattern of keeping overwriting the same state using outcome of a series of APIs which are generally async with unclear time to complete or fail.

> Will altering state in each useEffect hook cause mutiple re-renders?

React can batch the series of re-renders triggered by `setStateForm` so there will be only one re-render. If `setStateForm` has to deal with Promises then React will not use batching, otherwise it may or may not.