# Semantic UI React: Problem with multiple useEffect calls in the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, semantic-ui-react

I would need to run 2 queries to my REST API for 2 dropdown elements in a component:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch('/movies').then(response =>
        response.json()).then(data =>
          setMovieOptions(data.map(x =>
          {
            return {'key': x.name, 'text': x.name, 'value': x.name}
          }))
        )
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch('/people').then(response =>
        response.json()).then(data =>
          setPersonOptions(data.map(x =>
            {
              return {'key': x.name, 'text': x.name, 'value': x.name}
            }))
          )
    }, [])
```

It looks like if I use `useEffect` more than once I lose the connection to the DB behind my REST API.
Am I missing something? Could you please help me?
I thank you in advance.

Theo

Comment: Hi Theo. See if this helps (promise.all) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55522601/1205368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your calls into a single `useEffect`, using `Promise.all`. This type of Promise takes an array of resolved fetch calls, and returns an array of results. At that point, you can do whatever you'd like with the results.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then(res =>
        res.json()
      ),
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2").then(res =>
        res.json()
      )
    ])
      .then(([result1, result2]) => {
        console.log(result1, result2);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
  return <div className="App" />;
}
```

Result:

[image]

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-shannon-2hnip?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288497/useeffect-not-working-with-multiple-dropdowns-in-semantic-ui-react