# useEffect not working with multiple dropdowns in Semantic UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am using Semantic UI React.
The following JS code does not work for me:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Dropdown, Form, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

export const MovieDropdown = () => {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState("");
  const [person, setPerson] = useState("");
  const [movieOptions, setMovieOptions] = useState([]);
  const [personOptions, setPersonOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
      fetch("/people").then(res =>
        res.json()
      ),
      fetch("/movies").then(res =>
        res.json()
      )
    ])
      .then(([res1, res2]) => {
        console.log(res1, res2);
        var make_dd = (rec) => {
            rec.map(x => {
              return {'key': x.name, 'text': x.name, 'value': x.name}
            })
        }
        setPersonOptions(make_dd(res1))
        setMovieOptions(make_dd(res2))

      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });

  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Field>
        <Dropdown
          placeholder="Select Movie"
          search
          selection
          options={movieOptions}
          onChange={(e, {value}) => setMovie(value)}
        />
      </Form.Field>
      <Form.Field>
        <Dropdown
          placeholder="Select Person"
          search
          selection
          options={personOptions}
          onChange={(e, {value}) => setPerson(value)}
        />
      </Form.Field>

    </Form>
  );
};
export default MovieDropdown;
```

Problem is that I lose the DB connection when running this component. I tried with MySQL and SQLite and it gives the same issue.
How to solve this? Should I have 1 fetch per component?
I thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
Theo

Comment: The [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is probably missing the dependency array as the second parameter - right now it's running every time the component renders which means it just keeps sending requests.

Comment: Although if this causes the DB connection to fail, you'll probably want to look into connection pooling with whatever DB library you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I dont know about the DB Connetion, but the remmended way of calling api in useEffect is like this:

```
useEffect({
 // your code here only once
},[])
```

OR,

```
useEffect({
 // your code here will run whenever id changes
},[id])
```

Your useEffect will run on every render,which is not recommended time/ way to make api calls.

Comment: How to address a double fetch?

Comment: I think you are asking how to know if your useEffect is being called twice. Just write console.log("API CALLED") in useEffect function. This string will be printed twice in your console. To check console, right click anywhere in browser -> inpect element -> console tab. Or press F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+I

Let me know, if I misundertood your question.

Comment: You can also check your api being called in Network tab. But to see this, first open dev tools (inpect element) and then make api call or refresh your page.

Comment: No, I need to run 2 queries to my REST API.

Comment: To run 2 apis initially, you are doing the right thing by using Promise.all(). Write it like this:

Promise.all([
      fetch("/people"),
      fetch("/movies")
    ]).then(response => {
//  your code here
)

Comment: I only get promises with the following code?
```
useEffect(() => {
      Promise.all([fetch("/people"), fetch("/movies")])
      .then( proms => proms.map(prom => prom.json()) )
      .then(([data1, data2]) => {
          console.log(data1, data2)
      })
    }, [])
```
How should I correct it?

Comment: You dont need to write .then twice. When your urls are called succssfully, then you will get the final result in proms.